# Expand expression in Spark Scala aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, expression, aggregation, expansion

I'm trying to convert a simple aggregation code from PySpark to Scala.

The dataframes:

```py
# PySpark
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([10, 100],),
     ([20, 200],)],
    ['vals'])
```

```scala
// Scala
val df = Seq(
    (Seq(10, 100)),
    (Seq(20, 200)),
).toDF("vals")
```

Aggregation expansion - OK in PySpark:

```py
df2 = df.agg(
    *[F.sum(F.col("vals")[i]).alias(f"col{i}") for i in range(2)]
)
df2.show()
# +----+----+
# |col0|col1|
# +----+----+
# |  30| 300|
# +----+----+
```

But in Scala...

```scala
val df2 = df.agg(
  (0 until 2).map(i => sum($"vals"(i)).alias(s"col$i")): _*
)
```

> ```
>          (0 until 2).map(i => sum($"vals"(i)).alias(s"col$i")): _*
>                                                               ^
> On line 2: error: no `: _*` annotation allowed here
>        (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
> ```

The syntax seems almost the same to this `select` which works well:

```scala
val df2 = df.select(
  (0 until 2).map(i => $"vals"(i).alias(s"col$i")): _*
)
```

Does expression expansion work in Scala Spark aggregations? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation of Dataset.agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#agg(expr:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame), you see that it first has a fixed parameter and then a list of unspecified length:

```scala
def agg(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): DataFrame
```

So you should first have any other aggregation, then for the second argument you can do the list expansion. So something like

```scala
val df2 = df.agg(
  first($"vals"), (0 until 2).map(i => sum($"vals"(i)).alias(s"col$i")): _*
)
```

or any other single aggregation in front of the list should work.
I don't know why it is like this, maybe it's a Scala limitation so you can't pass an empty list and have no aggregation at all?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and showing how to read Scala documentation.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not fully understanding why this is happening for the compiler but it seems that it is not unpacking your Seq[Column] to vararg as params.

as @RvdV has mentioned in his post, the signature of the method is
def agg(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): DataFrame

so a temp solution is you unpack it manually, like:

```
val seq = Seq(0, 1).map(i => sum($"vals"(i)).alias(s"col$i"))
val df2 = df.agg(seq(0), seq(1))
```